# Wrong rotation behavior of UINavigationController embedded in Container View

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, uicontainerview

I am currently facing inconsistency of UINavigationController rotation behavior. 
I have an example with the following controller hierarchy:

TopLevelControllerWithContainerView->UINavigationController->topControllerOfNavController.
Let's simplify it by calling them A->B->C

The view sizes in rotation/lifecycle callbacks of **A** and **B** are as expected and described in documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html) in Fig.12-2. Here is example by rotation from Portrait to Landscape:

```
traitcollectiondidchange:
(736.0, 414.0)

viewdidlayoutsubviews:
(736.0, 414.0)

viewdidlayoutsubviews:
(736.0, 414.0)
```

However, the behavior of **C** is different:

```
traitcollectiondidchange:
(414.0, 736.0)

viewdidlayoutsubviews:
(414.0, 736.0)

viewdidlayoutsubviews:
(736.0, 414.0)
```

The right size is only available on the second *viewdidlayoutsubviews* call. The examples are taken from a clean and simple project setup, there is nothing there which could produce side effect. Here a screenshot from the used storyboard:

[image: Storyboard snapshot]

This issue doesn't exist if we exclude **A**, it only exists if UINavigationController is embedded as a childViewController.

Seems to me like a UIKit bug. Anyone else faced the issue or has any suggestion?